# stripe.createPaymentMethod() error on iOS Simulator but works on Android simulator

Tags: ios, react-native, stripe-payments, ios-simulator, stripes

I'm using stripe in my react-native-app but i'have a problem with the iOS simulators.
In fact, when using the android simulators the stripe.createPaymentMethod() works good but i have this error using the IOS Simulators :

```
{"code": "Failed", "declineCode": null, "localizedMessage": "This payment type is not supported yet", "message": "This payment type is not supported yet", "stripeErrorCode": null, "type": null}
```

InitStripe Code :

```
import {initStripe, StripeProvider} from '@stripe/stripe-react-native';
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';

let Application = () => {

 useEffect(() => {
  let initStrip = async () => {

  await initStripe({
    merchantIdentifier: 'merchant.identifier',
    publishableKey: 'key',
  }).then(res => console.log('init'));};
   initStrip();}, []);

  return <App />;
};

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => Application);
```

Someone could help me ?

Thanks

Comment: What does your code that calls `stripe.createPaymentMethod()` look like?

Answer (score 0):

Stripe ios emulator not working.Run on real device.That's what I did and it worked.